# 3D Dice using Maya - for integration with iOS game app

Tags: ios, maya

My designer is building a 3D design of a dice using Maya.

I want to integrate this in my iOS app so that the user can spin the dice and get a number. Then they play the game using that number.

So, I have two questions:
1) How can I make the dice spin and stop at a random position so that a number is presented to the user?

and

2) Once it stops spinning how can I detect the number that is displayed to the user (programmatically)?

Many thanks.
-Anil

Comment: Which engine you are using for your iOS Game ?